# How to parameterize a stored procedure in snowflake and assign parameter in FROM clause

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've written a stored procedure in snowflake as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DEV_NMC_ITEM_AND_PSYCHOMETRIC_DM.STAGE2B."sp_test"("STAGE_S3" VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE SQL 
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS '
DECLARE
            Stage_nm_s3 STRING;
              
begin

     truncate table "STAGE2A"."T001_IRF_STUDENT_FORM_S3";

     

COPY INTO "STAGE2A"."T001_IRF_STUDENT_FORM_S3"
FROM ( 
select 

a bunch of columns here........

from @stage2a.:stage_s3)
file_format = ( format_name = F_CSV type=csv)
pattern= ''.*_IRF_.*\\.csv'';
```

I am trying to assign the input parameter in the from clause but it's not working. I've tried uppercase, lowercase, double and single quotes but none of these worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use execute immediate to build query and concatenate procedure parameter variable. Refer example below -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.sp_test("STAGE_S3" VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
DECLARE
Stage_nm_s3 STRING;
begin
execute immediate 'COPY INTO public.TRANS_1 
FROM ( select $1 from @public.'||:stage_s3||') 
file_format = (type=csv, skip_header=1)';
return 'P';
end;
$$
;
+----------------------------------------+
| status                                 |
|----------------------------------------|
| Function SP_TEST successfully created. |
+----------------------------------------+
select * from trans_1;
+----+
| ID |
|----|
+----+
call sp_test('TEST_STAGE');
+---------+
| SP_TEST |
|---------|
| P       |
+---------+

select * from trans_1;
+------+
|   ID |
|------|
| 1234 |
|    5 |
+------+
```

Comment: Pankaj, I've used ```from @stage2a.'||:STAGE_S3||')``` but I'm getting error. I believe I'm using wrong syntax